# How does an ADC read non-constant voltage?

Tags: adc

I have a somewhat slow ADC the [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1114.pdf?&ts=1589124691168) with a measly 860 SPS (about 1ms per sample.)

Assuming perfect conditions, I would like to know what would this ADC spit out:

[image]

Here we have a saw wave of 1 volt peak to peak (forgot to place units on y axis, assuming the low peak is 0C and high peak is 1V).

If the ADC starts reading at millisecond 2 what would it read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ADS1115 is a sigma delta ADC that takes high-speed samples at 250 kHz and, averages many samples to bring you to a net sample rate of 860 Sps. Because of this, the final reading will be an average of the input waveform over the previous 1.162 ms sampling period.

[image]

Comment: I see, is this how all sigma delta ADCs work? By taking high speed samples and average them out ? So with the example i mention the output voltage would be the voltage at 2.5 ms ? I know of 2 more type (SAR, and Pipeline) how do they differ to this one?

Comment: @Jakequin to avoid confusion just use the 860 Sps timing and not some made up 1 ms timing. So, if you started sampling at 2.5 ms and finished sampling at 3.163 ms then the digital result will be the average of the analogue voltage waveform between those two points. How pipeline and SAR differ - massively and far, far too much to go into in comments - raise a new question for this but, there are answers probably on this site that you should search for first.

Comment: Alright thank you for the answer as always !